# Filter for ng-repeat via select if values from different arrays | Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to make filter with select in angular way if values of select from the different scope?

My code:

**JS**

```
$rootScope.isPublicScope = [
    {
        status: 0,
        name  : 'Not published'
    },
    {
        status: 1,
        name  : 'Published'
    },
    {
        status: 2,
        name  : 'Deleted'
    }
]
```

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <select class="form-control"
            ng-init="isPublic = isPublicScope[1]"
            ng-model="isPublic"
            ng-options="isPublic.name for isPublic in isPublicScope">
    </select>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="category in categories | filter:{is_public: isPublic.status}">
    <td>{{category.name}}</td>
    ...
</tr>
```

**Update:**
Solved.
I've updated my question if anyone is interested.

Comment: Hi,there is a option to answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: @K.Toress thanks) Next time I'll be aware of this)

Answer (score 0):

Use function on select `ng-change="changeFilter($event)"`

```
<select ng-model="status" ng-change="changeFilter($event)"
        ng-options="isPublic.status for isPublic in isPublicScope">
    <option value="">Status</option>
 </select>


<tr ng-repeat="category in categories">
 <td>{{category.name}}</td>
 ...
</tr>
```

**Controller**

And in your controller function use [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

```
$scope.changeFilter = function($event) {

  $scope.categories  = $filter('filter')($scope.categories, {status:$scope.status} )
}
```

Do not forget to inject `$filter` into your Controller function

Comment: I've found more clear solution) Please see the updated question! Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: sure, but , you should avoid to bring  much complexity into HTML, better solution is to get some controller function to handle this kind of functionality :)